# Как определить протокол: HTTPS или HTTP в PHP?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, http, https

Как определить протокол: HTTPS или HTTP в PHP? Скрипт запускается под PHP 5.5 (и выше) и Apache 2.4 (может быть также Apache 2.2 и Nginx)

На данный момент для определения я использую переменную $_SERVER['https'] и $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']:

```
if ((isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] === 'https') OR (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) AND $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on'))
    $protocol = 'https';
else
    $protocol = 'http';
```

Подскажите, каким еще образом можно выполнить определение протокола в PHP-скрипте: HTTPS или HTTP?

Comment: чем вас просто `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` не устраивает?

Comment: Тем, что возможно, этой переменной может не быть?

Comment: В конфиге в зависимости от сервера ставите присвоение `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = УСЛОВИЕ ? 'on' : 'off';` по условию подходящему к этому серверу. И в своем коде оставляете только проверку `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот код отлично работает на разных серверах.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
    $scheme = $_SERVER['HTTPS'];
else
    $scheme = '';
if (($scheme) && ($scheme != 'off')) $scheme = 'https';
else $scheme = 'http';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
    $protocol = 'https://';
} else {
    $protocol = 'http://';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Простой пример насильного перехода на https если был запрошен http
    if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit();
    };
```

Comment: Какое отношение этот код имеет к вопросу?

Answer (score 0):

```
$protocol = "http".(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "s" : "");
```