# Вставить в код url адрес домена

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста в код ниже, вставить ROOT домен, не страницу нахождения а именно домен.
Вставить нужно перед video/

```
<?php
//$params = [];
$params = array();

$url = Main::href("video/{$yt->id}");

if($_GET['new']) {
    $params['new'] = $_GET['new'];
}

if($_GET['url']) {
    $params['url'] = $_GET['url'];
}

if(!empty($params)){
  $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);  
}
echo "    <meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"$url\">\n";

echo "    <link rel=\"canonical\" href=\"$url\" />";

?>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: `$url = ROOT . $url;`

Comment: Не могу вставить в $url = Main::href("video/{$yt->id}");
если просто перед video/{$yt->id} вставить - ошибка.

Comment: Перед `echo` меняйте.

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал так      $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);  
Можно к этому коду добавить http|https на автомате? Сейчас идет домен.ру без http вначале...

Comment: Прочитайте про уязвимости в использовании `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` https://habrahabr.ru/post/166855/ И зачем у вас 2 знака равно в одной строке интересно знать? По http/https можете глянуть этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/645482/186083 и от него отталкиваться. Можете посмотреть как во фреймворках вопрос решается.